# Kendo UI DataSource JSONP external callback function name Not Working

Tags: kendo-ui, jsonp

I put my callback call directly in the kendo datasource example and I am unable to get this to render.  What am I missing?

The datasource will not load and I keep getting a type error. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code that I entered into a kendo dojo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" class="k-content">

    <div class="demo-section k-header wide">
        <div id="products"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <div class="product">
            <img src="../content/web/foods/#= ImageURL #.jpg" alt="#: ProductName # image" />
            <h3>#:Description#</h3>
            <p>#:kendo.toString(CurPrice, "c")#</p>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "//justclickzmedia.net/Search/Get/?callback=callback&query=coach+handbag",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                },
                requestStart: function() {
                    kendo.ui.progress($("#products"), true);
                },
                requestEnd: function() {
                    kendo.ui.progress($("#products"), false);
                },
                change: function() {
                    $("#products").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
                }
            });

            dataSource.read();
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #products {
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
/*            height: 510px;
            overflow: auto;*/
        }
        .product {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 111px;
            height: 170px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .product img {
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;
        }
        .product h3 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 3px 5px 0 0;
            max-width: 96px;
            overflow: hidden;
            line-height: 1.1em;
            font-size: .9em;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #999;
        }
        .product p {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .product:hover p {
            visibility: visible;
            position: absolute;
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;
            top: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 110px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            transition: background .2s linear, color .2s linear;
            -moz-transition: background .2s linear, color .2s linear;
            -webkit-transition: background .2s linear, color .2s linear;
            -o-transition: background .2s linear, color .2s linear;
        }
        .k-listview:after {
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post details on the error you are getting?

Comment: In your dataSource.transport.read object, have you tried specifying the jsonpCallback name ?  jsonpCallback: 'callback' ?

Comment: yes.. I tried to put the jsonpCallback name in the datasource call but I did not have any luck with that either.

Comment: The error was type error datatype error.  I can get the exact error later today.

Comment: Here is the error that I am receiving.  TypeError - kendo.data.DataSource is not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer for the OP but in case someone comes here getting "TypeError - kendo.data.DataSource is not a constructor." check to see if you're accidentally including kendo.core.min.js instead of kendo.**ui**.core.min.js

Comment: Also I created a dojo from the OP's ode and simply changed the datasource URL and template and got no errors: http://dojo.telerik.com/IzAWU - my guess is that perhaps there was an issue loading kendo and that caused the OPs "TypeError - kendo.data.DataSource is not a constructor." error?